# Show the name of month in datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

May I know the DateTime local value can show the name of the month?

For example my current code:

```html
<Form.Control
type="date"
name="startDate"
value={"2022-09-20"} 
min={"2022-09-20"}  
/>
```

The result is shown below:

[image: img1]

Now my problem is I want to show 20 Sep 2022 on the screen like the below picture. Is it possible?

[image]

If I use `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` to create date picker should be ok. But now I want to use form control date type to create date picker. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problems. Thanks.

Comment: Which date picker package or library you are using currently?

Comment: Just using reactjs